Is this a typo in Sydsaeter's book of image definition?
On page 543 of the textbook Further Mathematics for Economic Analysis (second edition), the definition of (direct) image is the following:
Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a function. The (direct) image under $f$ of a subset $S$ of $A$ is the set
$f(S) = \{y \in B: y = f(x) \space \text{for some} \space x \in A\}$
I feel like we should say "for some $x \in S \subseteq A$" instead. So I am just wondering if it is a typo?

I think you are right, it seems like a typo.

Definitely a typo.
